# Accessing values from a method to another method

Tags: c#, methods

**How do i access values from ReadInput() method so that i can use num1 and num2 for addition in Addition() method**

````
    public class HelloWorld
            {
                public void ReadInput()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Insert a first number:");
                    var num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        
                    Console.WriteLine("Insert a second number");
                    var num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                public void Addition()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Addition");
                    ReadInput();
                    int sum = num1 + num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("The sum is " + sum);
                }
    ```
````

Comment: You can make `num1`, `num2` member veriables of class `HelloWorld`. Then you'll be able to access them from all the class [non static] methods.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to `3dd's` opinion, you should not call `Addition` method in the `ReadInput` method, because the `ReadInput` method, as its name suggests, is only responsible for reading inputs, Also, the `Addition` method's only task is to perform addition and send the result to the caller so that the caller can use as it wants. and if you call `Addition` inside `ReadInput`, you have violated the [SRP principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).,
You can optimize your code as follows. Consider the output for the `ReadtInput` method and the input and output for the `Addition` method.

you can use [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) or create a separate model, I will write both for you.

with Tuple :

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public (int number1, int number2) ReadInput()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Insert a first number:");
        var num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Insert a second number");
        var num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        return (num1, num2);
    }

    public int Addition(int num1, int num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Addition");

        int sum = num1 + num2;

        return sum;
    }
}
```

How to use :

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();

        var result = helloWorld.ReadInput();

        var sumResult = helloWorld.Addition(result.number1, result.number2);

        Console.WriteLine("The sum is " + sumResult);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use tuple, you create a model like below, the changes are as follows :

```
public class ReadInputModel
{
   public int Number1 { get; set; }
   public int Number2 { get; set; }
}
```

And the `ReadInput` method changes as follows

```
public ReadInputModel ReadInput()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Insert a first number:");
    var num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

     Console.WriteLine("Insert a second number");
     var num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

     return new ReadInputModel
     {
            Number1 = num1,
            Number2 = num2
     };
}
```

***Just pay attention to this point, I only optimized you Code, but still the principles of creating and designing methods are not well followed,for example, you should not do `Console.WriteLine` in the `ReadInput` method and its only task should be to read information ,and other things which I think cannot be explained here, it is better to study the principles of Solid well.***

***I recommend reading these articles:***

[Solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)

[SOLID Principles In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/damubetha/solid-principles-in-C-Sharp/)

[Csharp best practices dangers of violating solid principles in csharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/csharp-best-practices-dangers-of-violating-solid-principles-in-csharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
            public void ReadInput()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert a first number:");
                var num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    
                Console.WriteLine("Insert a second number");
                var num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Addition(num1 , num2);
            }
            public void Addition(int num1, int num2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Addition");
                int sum = num1 + num2;
                Console.WriteLine("The sum is " + sum);
            }
```

Comment: using Week_01.HelloCS;

HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld();

hello.Addition(int num1, int num2);    Should I be passing num1 and num2 to this as well?

Comment: You've now created an infinite loop.